# Using LPEG (Lua Parser Expression Grammars) like boost::spirit

Tags: parsing, boost-spirit, peg, lpeg

So I am playing with lpeg to replace a boost spirit grammar, I must say boost::spirit is far more elegant and natural than lpeg. However it is a bitch to work with due to the constraints of current C++ compiler technology and the issues of TMP in C++. The type mechanism is in this case your enemy rather than your friend. Lpeg on the other hand while ugly and basic results in more productivity.

Anyway, I am digressing, part of my lpeg grammar looks like as follows:

```
function get_namespace_parser()
  local P, R, S, C, V =
    lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S, lpeg.C, lpeg.V

namespace_parser = 
lpeg.P{
    "NAMESPACE";
    NAMESPACE   = V("WS") * P("namespace") * V("SPACE_WS") * V("NAMESPACE_IDENTIFIER") 
                  * V("WS") * V("NAMESPACE_BODY") * V("WS"),

    NAMESPACE_IDENTIFIER = V("IDENTIFIER") / print_string ,
    NAMESPACE_BODY =  "{" * V("WS") *   
                      V("ENTRIES")^0 * V("WS") * "}",


    WS = S(" \t\n")^0,
    SPACE_WS = P(" ") * V("WS") 
}
  return namespace_parser
end
```

This grammar (although incomplete) matches the following `namespace foo {}`. I'd like to achieve the following semantics (which are common use-cases when using boost spirit).

1. Create a local variable for the namespace rule.
2. Add a namespace data structure to this local variable when `namespace IDENTIFIER {` has been matched.
3. Pass the newly created namespace data structure to the `NAMESPACE_BODY` for further construction of the AST... so on and so forth.

I am sure this use-case is achievable. No examples show it. I don't know the language or the library enough to figure out how to do it. Can someone show the syntax for it.

**edit :** After a few days of trying to dance with lpeg, and getting my feet troden on, I have decided to go back to spirit :D it is clear that lpeg is meant to be weaved with lua functions and that such weaving is very free-form (whereas spirit has clear very well documented semantics). I simply do not have the right mental model of lua yet.

Answer (score 1):

Though "Create a local variable for the namespace rule" sounds disturbingly like "context-sensitive grammar", which is not really for LPEG, I will assume that you want to build an abstract syntax tree.

In Lua, an AST can be represented as a nested *table* (with named and indexed fields) or a closure, doing whatever task that tree is meant to do.

Both can be produced by a combination of nested LPEG *captures*.

I will limit this answer to AST as a Lua table.

Most useful, in this case, LPEG captures will be:

- `lpeg.C( pattern )` -- simple capture,
- `lpeg.Ct( pattern )` -- table capture,
- `lpeg.Cg( pattern, name )` -- named group capture.

The following example based on your code will produce a simple syntax tree as a Lua table:

```
local lpeg = require'lpeg'
local P, V = lpeg.P, lpeg.V
local C, Ct, Cg = lpeg.C, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.Cg
local locale = lpeg.locale()
local blank = locale.space ^ 0
local space = P' ' * blank
local id = P'_' ^ 0 * locale.alpha * (locale.alnum + '_') ^ 0

local NS = P{ 'ns',
                  -- The upper level table with two fields: 'id' and 'entries':
    ns          = Ct( blank * 'namespace' * space * Cg( V'ns_id', 'id' )
                    * blank * Cg( V'ns_body', 'entries' ) * blank ),
    ns_id       = id,
    ns_body     = P'{' * blank
                         -- The field 'entries' is, in turn, an indexed table:
                       * Ct( (C( V'ns_entry' )
                       * (blank * P',' * blank * C( V'ns_entry') ) ^ 0) ^ -1 )
                       * blank * P'}',
    ns_entry    = id
}
```

- `lpeg.match( NS, 'namespace foo {}' )` will give:

  ```
  table#1 {
      ["entries"] = table#2 {
      },
     ["id"] = "foo",
  }
  ```
- `lpeg.match( NS, 'namespace foo {AA}' )` will give:

  ```
  table#1 {
      ["entries"] = table#2 {
          "AA"
      },
     ["id"] = "foo",
  }
  ```
- `lpeg.match( NS, 'namespace foo {AA, _BB}' )` will give:

  ```
  table#1 {
      ["entries"] = table#2 {
          "AA",
          "_BB"
      },
     ["id"] = "foo",
  }
  ```
- `lpeg.match( NS, 'namespace foo {AA, _BB, CC1}' )` will give:

  ```
  table#1 {
      ["entries"] = table#2 {
          "AA",
          "_BB",
          "CC1"
      },
     ["id"] = "foo",
  }
  ```